# Automatic sequential numbering with decimals based on arbitrary senority using VBA code on excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'd like Excel to automatically number each row I add with a sequential unique identifier that is dependent on the level of seniority that I've assigned to the row. (For example, if the row is a level 2, the task no. should be 2.1; if the next task is a level 1, the task no. should be 3). Lastly, I'd like it to be dynamic so if I were to add a row in the middle of the list, all the subsequent task no.s should become greater.

I founded pieces of VBA codes online but none that fits my purpose exactly. Was wondering if anyone has something for this purpose. Thanks for your help!

```
Level | Task No. 
  1   | 1
  2   | 1.1
  2   | 1.2
  1   | 2
  2   | 2.1
  2   | 2.2
  1   | 3
  2   | 3.1
```

See illustration of table here:

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between a 2.2 and a 3.1.2 ?

Comment: What's your code like, which part are you stumped on?

Comment: Why is the last one 3.1.2 and not 3.1.1 ?

Comment: Column one is hardcoded and used to denote the level of senority. Think of 2 as "apples", 2.2 as "apple is bitten" and eg. 2.2.1 as "mouth opens to bite the apple". 

3.1.2 in this case would be another high level task (in this example it would be something like "pear is washed with water")

The last one should also be 3.1.1 instead of 3.1.2 - good call Tim!

Answer (score 0):

No comments, but you should be able to follow...

```
Sub Label()
    Const MAX_LEVELS As Long = 10
    Dim levels(1 To MAX_LEVELS) As Long, i As Long, x As Long
    Dim c As Range, s
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        s = ""
        i = c.Value
        levels(i) = levels(i) + 1
        For x = i + 1 To MAX_LEVELS
            levels(x) = 0
        Next x
        For x = 1 To i
            s = s & IIf(s <> "", ".", "") & levels(x)
        Next x
        With c.Offset(0, 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = s
        End With
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note it does not check you've been following the numbering scheme correctly (ie. if you go straight from level 1 to level 4 it won't warn you)